# AppOffline error with MVC 2 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have installed my ASP.NET MVC 2 app to our QA servers.  I set up a virtual directory and an app pool.  Both have been started.  But when I got the URL I get the error Service Unavailable.  Not sure what this is?  If I go to the log files in C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\HTTPERR then the only error that I see is:

```
2010-11-09 11:59:00 [IP removed] 10.58.10.79 80 HTTP/1.1 GET / 503 1118619102 AppOffline HBFGA
```

IIS is running on Windows 2003.

Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This indicates](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/windowsserver2003/library/iis/55f71614-ef1b-4015-b9c8-a42c1e700c25.mspx?mfr=true) that there's some problem with the application pool. You may take a look at the server Event Log for further details as to why it has failed.